# Access IndexedDB from different domain with CORS?

Tags: local-storage, cors, indexeddb

Is it somehow possible with CORS to access data in an IndexedDB on domain A from domain B. I guess the answer to this question pretty much also applies to localStorage/sessionStorage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the same database from multiple domains, the access scope is limited to [html origin](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/origin-0.html).

```
html_Origin = protocol + "://" + url + ":" + port + "/";
```

Additional explanation by [Raymond Camden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52160/raymond-camden):
CORS is about http requests to different servers. IndexedDB isn't on a different server - it is on the client.

Comment: I'm aware of the restriction but was wondering whether CORS helps to circumenvent that?

Comment: CORS is about http requests to different servers. IndexedDB isn't on a different server -it is on the client.

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB API is not accessible from different origin by security design. However, you can communicate and transfer data between cross origin documents via [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, There is a pretty big leak in Safari 15 on all platforms currently that allows you to get the `names` of the databases.

More details here https://fingerprintjs.com/blog/indexeddb-api-browser-vulnerability-safari-15/